# creating a 3d image in java help please

Tags: java

I really need help with the java program...i am getting errors when i am running the programs.
My goal for this lab is to combine two images into a single 3 dimension image. These images will be viewed using red/blue glasses to give the 3D effect. The final image will attempt to be a grayscale of the object in the original original images. I have to verify that the two images have the same width and height before attempting to create the 3D image. If the images do not match, print out an error message and exit the program.

error:  width cannot be resolved

```
    height cannot be resolved
```

### i wrote the program as below...

```
public class 3dImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Access and open the picture
        String filename = FileChooser.pickAFile ();
        Picture p1 = new Picture (filename);

        //second picture
        String filename2 = FileChooser.pickAFile ();
        Picture p2 = new Picture (filename);

        //get the width and height from p1 and p2
        Picture p3;
        p3 = new Picture (width, height);

        // call the method to modify the Pictture
        modifyPicture (p1, p2, p3);

        // explore (display) the picture    
        p3.explore();
    }  // end of main


    public static void modifyPicture (Picture p1, Picture p2, Picture p3) {

        // get the width and height of the picture
        int width = p1.getWidth();
        int height = p1.getHeight();

        //shows width and height
        System.out.println ("Width: " + width + ", Height: " + height);

        // loop over the pixels
        for (int xPos = 0 ; xPos < width ; ++xPos) {
            for (int yPos = 0 ; yPos < height ; ++yPos) {         
                //  access the pixel to be modifed
                Pixel pix1 = p1.getPixel (xPos, yPos);
                Pixel pix2 = p2.getPixel (xPos, yPos);
                Pixel pix3 = p3.getPixel (xPos, yPos);  

                // modify the pixel 

                int redAmount = pix1.getRed (255);
                int greenAmount = pix1.getGreen (0);
                int blueAmount = pix1.getBlue (0);                
                int grayAmount1 = (int)(redAmount * 0.299 + greenAmount * 0.587 + blueAmount * 0.114);   

                redAmount = pix2.getRed(0);
                greenAmount = pix2.getGreen(255);
                blueAmount = pix2.getBlue(255);
                int grayAmount2 = (int)(redAmount * 0.299 + greenAmount * 0.587 + blueAmount * 0.114);

                pix3.setRed (grayAmount1);
                pix3.setGreen (grayAmount2);
                pix3.setBlue (grayAmount2);
                // …
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am stuck here and i need help..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do right now that you're stuck on?

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you done so far?

Comment: Are you able to provide the exact errors you're receiving when you attempt to execute the code?

Comment: i can't figure it out how to call width and height of the picture...

Comment: i am getting errors when i am running..

----------------
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
 at sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(Unknown Source)
 at SimplePicture.getBasicPixel(SimplePicture.java:300)
 at Pixel.getAlpha(Pixel.java:72)
 at Pixel.setRed(Pixel.java:258)
 at project2jpatel.modifyPicture(project2jpatel.java:94)
 at project2jpatel.main(project2jpatel.java:34)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke

Comment: i am not sure if i have put down the correct code for picture 3

Comment: can someone help whts wrong with my program

Comment: @user1002118 please edit your original question to include the error in a readable fashion.  No one can understand it in that comment.  Also remember that the code you posted does not have line numbers.  Either add line numbers or comment for us where the exception occurs.

Comment: i have error where i called  p3=new Picture (width, height);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p3 = new Picture (width, height);
```

Neither `width` nor `height` has been declared. You need to declare them and set to appropriate  values. As you did in `modifyPicture` function.

Make sure `p1`, `p2` and `p3` have the same size, otherwise `modifyPicture` won't work correctly.

Comment: how do i declare the width and height?

Comment: int width = p1.getWidth ();

int height = p1.getHeight ();

i don't know if this is correct.

Comment: can somebody tell me how do i code the width and height of all 3 pictures?